# How can I retrieve clean text inside HTML tags using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a form which is accepts HTML data, but we need only their respective text, not anything else. Is there any particular way to extract the text out of the HTML in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: it doesn't work perfectly for me here is an example :
$htmlVar = "&lt;div &quot;&gt;آمار و احتمالات کاربردی&ltstyle=&quot;font-size: small; &quot;&gt;ن رشته&amp;zwnj;&amp;rlm;هاى علوم ادارى، مديريت، بازرگانى، اقتصاد، حسابدارى و ساير رشته&amp;zwnj;&amp;rlm;هاى وابسته تنظيم و تدوين شده است.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: justify; &quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center; &quot;&gt;100921&lt;/div&gt;";


echo (strip_tags($htmlVar));
Note: due to insufficient space I've deleted some of the html code.

Comment: That is no HTML Code. Try echo (strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($htmlVar)));

Answer (score 2):

Surely it can be done:

Just look at this function and use it as you like:

```
function html2txt ($document)
{
    $search = array (
            "'<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>'si", // Strip out JavaScript code
            "'<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>'si",          // Strip out HTML tags
            "'([\r\n])[\s]+'",                // Strip out white space
            "'@<![\s\S]*?â��[ \t\n\r]*>@'",   
            "'&(quot|#34|#034|#x22);'i",      // Replace HTML entities
            "'&(amp|#38|#038|#x26);'i",       // Added hexadecimal values
            "'&(lt|#60|#060|#x3c);'i",
            "'&(gt|#62|#062|#x3e);'i",
            "'&(nbsp|#160|#xa0);'i",
            "'&(iexcl|#161);'i",
            "'&(cent|#162);'i",
            "'&(pound|#163);'i",
            "'&(copy|#169);'i",
            "'&(reg|#174);'i",
            "'&(deg|#176);'i",
            "'&(#39|#039|#x27);'",
            "'&(euro|#8364);'i",         // Europe
            "'&a(uml|UML);'",            // German
            "'&o(uml|UML);'",
            "'&u(uml|UML);'",
            "'&A(uml|UML);'",
            "'&O(uml|UML);'",
            "'&U(uml|UML);'",
            "'&szlig;'i",
            );
    $replace = array (    "",
                "",
                " ",
                "\"",
                "&",
                "<",
                ">",
                " ",
                chr(161),
                chr(162),
                chr(163),
                chr(169),
                chr(174),
                chr(176),
                chr(39),
                chr(128),
                "Ã¤",
                "Ã¶",
                "Ã¼",
                "Ã�",
                "Ã�",
                "Ã�",
                "Ã�",
            );

    $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $document);

    return trim ($text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the HTML using [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) and extract what you need.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("data.html");
$metaTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
// Process $metaTags
```